# How to skip from creating a new Pool process for every iteration?

Tags: for-loop, python-multiprocessing

I have the following code snippet

```
for self.step in range(0, num_steps):
                
    with torch.no_grad():
        pool = mp.Pool(4)

        self.step_iter = np.full(shape=len(self.env.agents), 
                                 fill_value=self.step, dtype=np.int)


        # select action for every agent
        action_vector = pool.starmap(Trajectory.select_action, 
                                     zip(self.replay_buffer,
                                         self.actors,
                                         self.critics,
                                         self.step_iter,
                                         self.action_size))
        pool.close()
        pool.join()
```

The problem is that for every timestep a new pool process is created (which takes some time).
Is there a way to reuse the same pool for every iteration until `self.step==num_steps`?

Comment: Try putting `pool = mp.Pool(4)` outside the loop (along with `close()` and `join()`)

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I did it before adding your comment. So there is not any problem if a process runs miltiple times, right?

Comment: The `pool` is a collection of task handlers that will handle task in the queue. Think of it as (4) cashiers in a store that handle the line of customers. When a cashier is available, they begin processing the next customer. The `pool` is the cashiers and the `starmap` creates the line of customers to be processed.

Comment: Very nice example! Thank you very much @Mike67!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

(moving comment to answer)

The `pool` is a collection of task handlers that will handle tasks in the queue. Think of it as (4) cashiers in a store that handle the line of customers. When a cashier is available, they begin processing the next customer. The `pool` is the cashiers and the `starmap` creates the line of customers to be processed.

You only need to create the pool (the cashiers) once:

```
pool = mp.Pool(4)  # process handlers
for self.step in range(0, num_steps):
                
    with torch.no_grad():
            
        self.step_iter = np.full(shape=len(self.env.agents), 
                                 fill_value=self.step, dtype=np.int)
    
        # select action for every agent
        action_vector = pool.starmap(Trajectory.select_action, 
                                     zip(self.replay_buffer,
                                         self.actors,
                                         self.critics,
                                         self.step_iter,
                                         self.action_size))
pool.close()
pool.join()
```